# LabVIEW 2009 holding onto data when I don't want it to

Tags: file, vi, labview

I'm new to LabVIEW but have been building a signal analyser code that takes the required data and prints it out to text files after the data has been taken. The problem I'm having is that when it makes a new file it holds on to the data from the previous run and prints that too which is not what I want. I've attached the LabVIEW vi (ver.2009), and any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Also if someone knows a better way of RMS-ing the data after each iteration than my mess of shift registers I'd be happy to see it.

[frequency analyser (fixed).vi](http://www.mediafire.com/?dkoci48y9lr0sn9)

Comment: I might be able to help, but cannot due to my old LV version. COuld you provide a screenshot of your wiring (if it is small enough)?

Comment: Here's a picture of the wiring, warning though it's a mess and the pic is quite large.
[frequency analyser wiring](http://www.mediafire.com/view/?hk3m697dgs2ue71)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your main question: the part of the code that builds the string (for loop with a shift register) stores the previous data each time you re-run the vi. What you need is to initialise the shift register with an empty string :

[image: vi]

Also a couple of notes/suggestions:

- You could avoid using shift registers in this case. Divide the DAQ part of the code into say 3 parts: acquire data in the first for loop (store into array), modify the array (you could then perhaps use the build-in RMS vi), visualise on the UI
- Build the code in smaller chunks, use subVi's
- Keep the code small, nice and tidy (check coding standards), add comments - this will really help you later

Comment: Thanks man! That's fixed the data problem. I'll definately look into splitting it up into smaller chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for advice on the RMS functionality you used I took a more detailed look of your code. And I may be harse, but it doesn't make sense (point by point):

- [image: For loop counter]

You ask the end user for a number of runs, and then you subtract one. Why? I guess it's because the read data before the for loop. (remove that one).

- The [Frequency RMS function](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361F-01/lvwave/fft_power_spectrum/) you use has support for avaraging, and has no limit of the number of averages. Specify the following configuration:
  [image: Use standard avaraging]

This will add RMS avaraging to you output data, and you can loose all your own calculation with shift registers.

- The following code is just plain wrong:

[image: Do not shift the frequency]

You only shift the data, without actually changing the data. By incrementing the starting frequency you shift the FFT. So a signal that was detected at 55 Hz, no is plotted at 56 Hz. To your end user this is misleading.

One thing you need to be aware of in your code is that you don't have continious sampling. Each iteration of you for loop your data acquisition is started and stopped. You can verify this by plotting the t0's of the waveform that is captured. You'll notice they don't start at a constant interval.
A better aproach is to use the task created by the Express VI in the first iteration:

[image: Reuse task].

However you should then change the acquisition mode to 'continious samples':

[image: Continuous samples]

Do not forget to close the task in the last iteration:

[image: Close task]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.


In the above picture where you detail how to get the FFT to average there's a box with multiple components in it, what is it and where do you get it? Also I assume the box with "number of averages" is a bundle by name box?

You've also mentioned that I'm only shifting the data and after a play with it I see what you mean, do you know how to fix this so that it actually takes the correct data range for the input frequencies? I'm doing multiple data ranges and this needs to be changeable (ie able to take ranges from 1-101Hz, 101-201Hz, etc.)
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's a bundle by name.
For the frequency ranges, you need to take a subset of the waveform. (there's a special function for that.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the shift register, you should work with an array which you empty before each run.

Comment: I don't know how to do that (when I say I'm new to labview, I really mean it unfortunately). Also if I empty the array before each run where do i store the data to be RMS-ed?